# How can i ignore .swift file in .gitignore

Tags: github, bitbucket

I have to push code on bitbucket and wanna ignore one StripeKeyManager.swift file, How can i do that? Anybody can help me to get rid out of this.
I'm doing like this but its not working.

**Note:**  ValetIT is main folder inside the project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I'm doing like this but its not working.

StripeKeyManager.swift is likely not a directory, so you probably want to remove the trailing slash in that line, making it just:

```
ValetIT/ProjectResources/Global/StripeKeyManager.swift
```